# JavaScript: Не получается добавить в массив отдельные слова из строки

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

Всем привет!
Недавно начал изучать javascript, до этого немного баловался java, возможно, поэтому и возникла проблема ниже. Нужно с помощью цикла из строки взять отдельные слова и их вставить в пустой массив, не используя метод `split()`. Пробовал код ниже, но выдает пустой массив. Подскажите. в чем проблема.

```
let sentence = 'Всем большой привет';
let list = [];
let word;
let start = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence.charAt(i) == " ") {
        word = sentence.substring(start, i);
        list.push(word);
        start = i;
    }
}
console.log(list);
```

Comment: вам бы вот прям внимательно почитать оператор цикла ваш. прям вот символ в символ до конца строки

Comment: @teran, там не только опечатка с `;` :)

Comment: Никогда не понимал зачем усложнять жизнь специально :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, чтобы потренироваться циклах, пушах и т.д.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У вас лишняя `;` внутри цикла `for` между условием и телом цикла. Поэтому все в принципе ломается, цикл не выполняется, а результат — пустой массив.
2. `start` — это позиция пробела. С текущим кодом пробел войдет в следующее слово. поэтому лучше сдвинуться на 1 позицию дальше
3. Вы слова ищите от прошлого места до пробела. Так последнее слово вы не найдете (после него же нет пробела). Как минимум просто прибавьте к строке пробел.

```js
let sentence = 'Всем большой привет';
sentence += ' ';
let list = [];
let word;
let start = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  if (sentence.charAt(i) == " ") {
    word = sentence.substring(start, i);
    list.push(word);
    start = i + 1;
  }
}
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: не учитывается вариант с дублирующимися пробелами :) и если пробел в начале строки

Comment: @Grundy такого не было в тз

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг нужен вариант с игнорированием любых пробелов, то вот он:

```js
const sentence = '         Всем          большой             привет          ';
const words = [];
let word = -1;
let startNewWord = true;

for (const symbol of sentence) {

    if (symbol === ' ') {
      if (startNewWord === false) startNewWord = true;
      continue;
    }
    
    if (startNewWord) {
      words[++word] = '';
      startNewWord = false;
    }
    
    words[word] += symbol;
}

console.log(words);
```

- Строки в JS прекрасно позволяют брать нужный символ как из массива с помощью `string[i]`, потому не вижу нужды в данном месте использовать метод `charAt(i)`
- Сравнения лучше делать с `===`, а не `==`
- Если у вас в коде есть `if` без `else`, то не стоит пихать весь код  в `if`, лучше вытащить всё из `if`, а в `if` написать обратное условие. Так код будет намного легче читать и понимать. Я понимаю что это не всегда возможно и нужно (например если всего 1 команда в `if`), но поверьте моему опыту в очень многих случаях это возможно
- Избегайте операций со строками как можно больше. В данном случае вам просто надо один раз пройтись по всем символам, а если каждый раз брать подстроку, то это скажется на скорости работы в больших строках

Answer (score -2):

```js
const string = 'Всем большой привет';

const splitString = text => {
  const str = text + ' ';
  const result = [];
  let word = '';
  for (const symbol of str) {
    if (symbol !== ' ') {
      word += symbol
    } else {
      result.push(word);
      word = '';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(splitString(string));
```